# Unable to get COUNT(*) result from structured SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on a SQL statement that checks the database to see if feedback has been left for a specific **qr_id** from a specific **uuid** within 24 hours. The original code works as intended, but obviously to be more secure I wanted to change the code to a structed SQL statement instead.

```
$uuid = "DB8962A3-BC7A-481F-9D7E-C1FC7F74E50E";
$qrid = "2147483647";
$query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `feedback` WHERE uuid = '%s' AND qr_id = '%s' AND created_on > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))", mysql_real_escape_string($uuid), $qrid);
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$size = $row['COUNT(*)'];
if ($size > 0){
    echo 'Unable to leave feedback as user has left feedback for this employee within 24 hours.';
}else{
    echo 'User has not left feedback for this employee within 24 hours, continue.';
}
```

The above works perfectly fine, if the count is above 0 then it stops the user posting. Here's my attempt at converting it to a structured SQL statement:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `feedback` WHERE uuid = ? AND qr_id = ? AND created_on > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))");
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $uuid, $qrID);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $size = $result['COUNT(*)'];
    $stmt->close();
    if ($size = 0){
        // do post, return true
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
        // do not post, return false
    }
```

I have tried printing the result value and it's always 1, and trying to echo the $size variable returns nothing.

Comment: Shouldn' t you be doing if ($size == 0 ){ instead of if ($size = 0 ){ and in your  query do something like  COUNT(*) ct and then $size = $result[ 'ct' ];

Comment: Neither of those worked, I did change over it over to == however the COUNT(*) ct did not work. At the minute it will return true indefinitely, although it should be false.

Comment: Have you tried using `var_dump($result);`to see if the query is returning anything?

Comment: Please use ($size==0) in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the result, try this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('si', $uuid, $qrID);
$stmt->execute();
//here you bind result to variable $size
$stmt->bind_result($size);
$stmt->fetch() 
$stmt->close();
if ($size == 0){
    // do post, return true
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
    // do not post, return false
}
```

Comment: you are using one equal sign here, it should be === for same type and value or == for the same value regardless of type.